Cgroups v2: Unable to set cpu.max in /sys/fs/cgroup/kubepods.slice
Whenever I try to set the cpu.max value in my kubepods.slice (or any other slice for that matter) I get a "permission denied" error:
echo "200000 1000000" > /sys/fs/cgroup/kubepods.slice/cpu.max

-bash: /sys/fs/cgroup/kubepods.slice/cpu.max: Permission denied

I think I have compiled my Kernel with all the necessary parameters, and I have this in my grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 cgroup_no_v1=all"

but I'm still struggling with this issue.
What can be the reason for not being allowed to set cpu.max in cgroup's virtual fs?
Additional information:
Linux: Gentoo with systemd instead of OpenRC
Kernel: v6.6.58
I was investigating this setting because I got the following error whenever I wanted to create a Kubernetes cluster with "kubeadm init". I got the following error in the logs:
"Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with RunContainerError: "failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: openat2 /sys/fs/cgroup/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod6d5f292ce9d2ea1b6e586a346b951178.slice/cri-containerd-487ff6e01f5da57d6541bb077c676b81993f2abf8c23627415aeca65f0a69354.scope/cpu.max: no such file
Thanks in advance for your help!

Is there a need to do this manually instead of using systemd tools?

Thanks for your comment, @grawity.
The search for cpu.max (I had not dealt with cgroups before) started when I found this error after trying to create a Kubernetes cluster.
Whenever I did:
kubeadm init
I got a Kubelet error:

Please post the error/above comment as an edit to your question.  Thanks!

Which user is attempting to write to the file?
